# How can I pass the output of a command (get-random) to a variable?

Tags: powershell, shell

I've been trying to get a script to work in PowerShell. I am trying to pass the output of the command:

```
get-random -maximum 3 -minimum 1
```

to the variable $rand.

If you could explain it, that'd be great

Comment: Have you at least tried to search for it?  `$rand = get-random -maximum 3 -minimum 1`

Answer (score 1):

The following should work

```
$rand = get-random -max 3 -min 1
```